# Should I use multiple ListViews?

Tags: android, listview

I have a RelativeLayout with different elements. I was planning to have two ListViews on it, but I have noticed there are some problems with scrolling. Since each ListView only shows a maximum of 5 rows should I try to make some kind of custom adapter to merge those ListViews? Or is it better to replace the ListView with a LinearLayout/RelativeLayout and add the rows as I get them manually? (like the first answer in here: [android listview display all available items without scroll with static header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778485/android-listview-display-all-available-items-without-scroll-with-static-header) ).

Which should be the proper way on doing this? or is there another way? Also, each row will have an OnClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two solutions if you'd like to keep your list... list-y, without having to prerender all the row Views like the above solution suggests (which can be slow to render, eats RAM and doesn't scale nicely to more than a screen or two of Views, but is a fine quick solution for smaller lists, though I'd just use a bunch of Views in a LinearLayout in a ScrollView rather than a ListView in that case).

1. Write a custom ListAdapter, overriding getItemViewType, getViewTypeCount and GetView to inflate the proper kind of view and recycle appropriately for your two types of views. You'll also either need to override getItem to contain custom logic for figuring out which set of source data to look in and to map the data accordingly, or mush the data down into one list of Objects (if you're using an arrayadapter) and cast in the getView method (probably a bit slower than handling it in the getItem without casting).
2. Just use [cwac-merge](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), a view-and-adapter wrapping adapter. You can put two ListAdapters into a MergeAdapter and set that as your single ListView's adapter.

Comment: I think I will try cwac-merge. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with scrolling. I never figured out how to have the ListView share vertical space with a different View, and have a single scrollbar for them both.

I worked around it by having everything that needs to scroll on the layout a row in the ListView.

Adding views as rows to a LinearLayout may have problems scaling up, but I think you'll be OK if you only have 10 rows in total. On 1st gen Android devices it'll probably start to get sluggish around 20 items (depends on Layout complexity obviously). ListView scales up by only inflating views as they come on screen.

So in answer to your question either of the two alternatives you suggest will be OK, but the LinearLayout option will be the easiest to code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please, could you elaborate more in your first solution?