# View that can handle adapters but is not scrollable

Tags: android, android-view, android-adapter, android-adapterview

Does a View that can handle adapters (e.g. ArrayAdapter) but is not scrollable exist?

I would not like to go into workarounds (e.g. disabling a ListView's scrolling feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Calling `getView` on an adapter returns a `View` that corresponds to the information provided from the adapter's `getItem` method. So you can do something like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
BaseAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(context, itemList);

for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    // you can pass in a recycled view instead of null
    View itemView = adapter.getView(i, null, layout);
    layout.addView(itemView);
}
```

ViewGroups such as `LinearLayout` aren't scrollable by themselves so this should work. I'm not sure why you would want to use an `Adapter` in this situation but that's up to you.

Comment: This is really nice. So basically adapters are "arrays" that contain views. To answer you why I need this: I would like to implement [quickreturn/scrolltricks](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) but I also call async functions (data from a db). I have found a ready library [QuickReturn for listviews](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView) but my code has become very dirty and sensitive. So I wanted to make it more lightweight. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following or refer to the mentioned links

```
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

References :
[Disable scrolling of a ListView contained within a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212890/disable-listview-scrolling)

[Disable scrolling in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this wau
1. Create your custom Listview like below and use it rather default ListView

public class MyCustomListView extends ListView {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private GestureDetector gDetector;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean isFling;

    private float mDiffX;
    private float mDiffY;
    private float mLastX;
    private float mLastY;

    /**
     * Overrides method
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // reset difference values
            mDiffX = 0;
            mDiffY = 0;

            mLastX = ev.getX();
            mLastY = ev.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            mDiffX += Math.abs(curX - mLastX);
            mDiffY += Math.abs(curY - mLastY);
            mLastX = curX;
            mLastY = curY;

            // don't intercept event, when user tries to scroll vertically
            if (mDiffX > mDiffY) {
                return false; // do not react to horizontal touch events, these
                                // events will be passed to your list item view
            }
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public MyCustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context mContext) {
    }
}
```