# List without scrolling

Tags: android, list, scroll

i need make a list that not have scrolling, because i will have two lists, and wish you had just one scroll, and they were wrap_content, there exist object to make it?

Thanks in advance

Sorry by my English

I up a image to you understand me

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img819/4513/m0u2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

More you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212890/disable-listview-scrolling).

You should set fixed height for each `ListView`, using `weight` in your xml.
The way to do this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487552/limit-height-of-listview-on-android).

Comment: Already tried this way but look what happens http://imageshack.com/a/img822/8676/hlb6.png