# Disable/Enable ListView Scroll Effect on listview's Button Click Event

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am having one custom list view, it contains `enable/disable` button on each list view item , When user tap on `enable/disable` button, list view scroll should be `enable/disable`

I have tried guide like [Disable scrolling of a ListView contained within a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212890/disable-listview-scrolling)  & [Disable scrolling in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview) and several others , But it disables entire list view , thus i am not able to click on button once list view disable.

Any hint / guide will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: can you please post what you have try ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana already mentioned on question what i have trid

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview

Comment: @HareshChhelana My issue is different, it's regarding enabling and disabling list view on button click event ,please read question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to override onTouchEvent and return false when you want to block the list?

Comment: overwrite touch event on both button works for me thanks