# How to disable scrolling of an item in ListView android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, scroll, android-adapter

I just want to protect my first item of list view from scrolling or to stick the first item at the top of my layout. I cannot use other layout for that.

Remember other elements must be scroll in that list view.

Can i do that and if yes tell me how ??(with array adapter or custom one or any other method to do that)

please help...

already visited [Disable scrolling of a ListView contained within a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212890/disable-listview-scrolling)

and [Disable scrolling in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview)'

but it disable whole list view.

Comment: Why don't you create you top layout first and add a list view below that?

Comment: Can't you have a linear layout with one fixed child element and one scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Header View:

```
mList.addHeaderView(yourFirstItemView);
```

Remember to inflate "yourFirstItemView", something like:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
yourFirstItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent);
```