# Achive Scroll without scrollView

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

Yesterday I attain one interview where he asked one question :

if in a layout one banner is there and bottom of this banner ListView is there. without using scroll view how you will scroll the screen.

Edited:

Suppose In the xml file Linear layoutis there. Then add banner into the linear layout(in ImageView), then ListView is there. Now scroll the screen. How it will scroll?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me....what is that exactly?

Comment: Just add your banner in ListView header.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778485/android-listview-display-all-available-items-without-scroll-with-static-header

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the same with the help of the getView() method of Custom adapter.
like the below:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view= convertView;
     if(view==null){
       if(position==0){ 
           view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageViewLayout, null);
       }else{
           view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.otherLayoutForListItem, null);
       }
     }else{

     }
}
```

I think this can help you
but if you don't want to include in this way than u have to handle some other scroll option of the list View