# How to resize a ListView programmatically

Tags: android

I'm working on a new application and i want to resize a ListView programmatically, for example from a ListView with params of 200x100 to a 100x100.

How can i resize the dimension of the ListView?

Comment: I would recommend you to include some code into your question. In that way, you have more chances to receive help and less chances to get your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Here is one way set the ListView's height programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861136/set-listview-height-programmatically

Comment: thanks but can you write me some code to set the height and the width?

Comment: Try layoutparams

Comment: @HasanKucuk can you write me a simple code to understand better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
         ArrayAdapter listAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) listView.getAdapter(); 
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }
            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }
```